# How to access JSONP data from Angular service in view using expressions

Tags: json, angularjs, service, jsonp, factory

I'm building an Angular based app to display data from the Strava API. I have tried using $http.get but i'd rather use a separate service so my code resides in a logic place so my controller isn't doing a lot, just call my service.

I have three files for this logic; the service, the controller and the view. The access token is obtained from Strava to get the account info in an external source.

In my service:

```
 /* Services */
 var access_token = "my_access_token";

stravaApp.factory('StravaActivities', function($resource) {
   return $resource('https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete/activities?access_token=' + access_token, {}, {
        getJSONP: {
          method: 'JSONP',
          isArray: true,
          params: {
              callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

In my controller

```
/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name stravaApp.controller:SitecontentCtrl
 * @description
 * # SitecontentCtrl
 * Controller of the stravaApp
 */

angular.module('stravaApp').controller('SitecontentCtrl', ['$scope', 'StravaActivities',
  function($scope, StravaActivities) {
    $scope.activities = StravaActivities.getJSONP();
  }]);
```

In my template/view

```
<ul class="act">
<li ng-repeat="act in activities | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp"
    class="thumbnail act-listing">
    <pre>{{activities | json }}</pre>
</li>
</ul>
```

The json files that is called is: https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete/activities?access_token=my_access_token&callback=angular.callbacks._0

I can't find a way to access the data in my view with expressions e.g {{ acts.id }}. When i use {{ act | json }} i receive the full JSON file but i cannot access a single part from the json with the solution i have tried. I think the problem is related to the callback. Since the Strava API doesn't support CORS i have to use JSONP.

I found a post with the exact problem, however no solution is provided and the code example is using $http.get and i want to use $resource for this in my service.

Can anyone provide me a solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: no real benefit using `$resource` since you can't post to a jsonp api. Does the API even serve jsonp? Not all API's do in which case would need to use a proxy

Comment: Well that makes sense. The fact that i was using $resource was just because i came across a neat example, no intention yet of posting data to the API. Strava does support JSONP (http://engineering.strava.com/strava-api-update/) so i wonder if it would work in the way i have in mind with $resource. If that would not work i have to use $http.get()

Comment: there is an `$http.jsonp` shorthand also  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp

Answer (score 0):

```
        (function() {
    app.controller('StravaController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http({ method: 'JSONP', url: 'https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete?per_page=1&access_token=your_token_here&callback=JSON_CALLBACK' }).success(function (data) {
            console.log('hello');
            $scope.athlete = data; // response data 
        }).
        error(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel really stupid right now. I received an answer from the developers. The problem was not related to angular at all. It seemed that in Strava the segments were marked as private so the API return a 401. I can now call any endpoint from my app.